# Numpy and 2-d array differences

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So far, i do what i want to do is as follows

```
ar2 = [[0 for t in range(maxy-miny)] for t in range(maxx-minx)]

for first,x in enumerate(range(minx, maxx)):
    for second,y in enumerate(range(miny, maxy)):
        ar2[first][second] = a[x][y]

io.imshow(ar2)
```

The problem is that it's really slow. So i'm considering numpy.

```
ar = np.zeros((maxx-minx, maxy-miny), dtype=np.ndarray) 

for first,x in enumerate(range(minx, maxx)):
    for second,y in enumerate(range(miny, maxy)):
        ar[first][second] = a[x][y] 

io.imshow(ar)
```

Though in the second case, the image won't show

```
TypeError: Image data can not convert to float
```

I tried to check what might be going on, so i tested ar[0] & ar2[0]

**Output of 2-d Array :**

> [array([230, 197, 204], dtype=uint8) 
>   array([241, 209, 214],
>   dtype=uint8)
>   array([233, 201, 206], dtype=uint8) array([214, 183,
>   188], dtype=uint8)...

**Output of Numpy Array :**

> [array([230, 197, 204]**,** dtype=uint8), 
>   array([241, 209, 214]**,** dtype=uint8),
>
> array([233, 201, 206], dtype=uint8), ...

So apparently, numpy is using commas but i can't understand how and why it happens.

Comment: @AndyHayden It's an 2d array of the original image. I have found which parts interest me, and i want to transfer them alone to a new one.

Comment: As @sebix says it's not a proper 2D numpy array (the dtype is not correct). The spaces vs commas thing is a red herring, that is purely how the objects are printed.

Comment: @AndyHayden How can i provide more info? Which part could be done differently? my a is done as follows "a = io.imread('C:\Users\Dimitrios\Desktop\polimesa\\punk.jpg')"

Comment: I can't promise anything myself, but usually helpful to provide reproducible example (i.e. something we can try at home), in this case this means showing us `a` or at least the first few elements/rows/columns of a.

Answer (score 1):

Your used dtype is not a valid number-like type, you used `np.ndarray` as type for individual values in your array.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ar = np.zeros((maxx-minx, maxy-miny))
a = plt.imread('something.jpg')

for first,x in enumerate(range(minx, maxx)):
    for second,y in enumerate(range(miny, maxy)):
        ar[first][second] = a[x][y] 

plt.imshow(ar)
```

This should work - however you haven't provided enough information to test that reliably.

I also recommend to use `plt` as abbreviation for `matplotlib.pyplot` instead of `io`, which can easily be mixed up with the actual io-module.

However, you can achieve the same goal but not looping at all:

```
ar3[0:maxx-minx, 0:maxy-miny] = a[minx:maxx,miny:maxy]
np.allclose(ar2, ar3)  # True
```

Comment: i get "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence" though . I also used "from skimage import io" before.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. Please provide a fully reproducible code piece. I also added a solution which works without loops.